# Save char array as JPG for C++ Windows Store App

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Given the following

- Bitmap raw image data in char array
- Image width and height
- Path `wzAppDataDirectory` in std::wstring generated using the following code

---

```
// Get a good path.
wchar_t wzAppDataDirectory[MAX_PATH];
wcscpy_s( wzAppDataDirectory, MAX_PATH, Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path->Data() );
wcscat_s( wzAppDataDirectory, MAX_PATH, (std::wstring(L"\\") + fileName).c_str() );
```

---

How can we save the image as JPG? (Include encoding as well as the char array is raw bitmap form)

Code example is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by save? Simply save, or also encode?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I refine my question to `Raw image data`. Hence, it includes encode as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example code which I obtained from my friend.

It uses OpenCV's Mat data structure. Note that, you need to ensure the unsigned char data array within `cv::Mat` is in continuous form. `cv::cvtColor` will do the trick (Or, `cv::Mat.clone`).

**Take note, do not use OpenCV's `imwrite`.** As at current time of writing, `imwrite` doesn't pass Windows Store Certification Test. It is using several APIs, which is prohibited in WinRT.

```
void SaveMatAsJPG(const cv::Mat& mat, const std::wstring fileName)
{
    cv::Mat tempMat;
    cv::cvtColor(mat, tempMat, CV_BGR2BGRA);

    Platform::String^ pathName = ref new Platform::String(fileName.c_str());

    task<StorageFile^>(ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync(pathName, CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)).
    then([=](StorageFile^ file)
    {
        return file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::ReadWrite);
    }).
    then([=](IRandomAccessStream^ stream)
    {
        return BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder::JpegEncoderId, stream);
    }).
    then([=](BitmapEncoder^ encoder)
    {
        const Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ pixels = ref new Platform::Array<unsigned char>(tempMat.data, tempMat.total() * tempMat.channels());
        encoder->SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode::Ignore, tempMat.cols , tempMat.rows, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
        encoder->FlushAsync();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a library to encode the JPEG.  Some possibilities are the [Independent JPEG Group's jpeglib](http://www.ijg.org/), [`stb_image`](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c), or [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/).